# How android sqlite databse will update in android market?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Currently I am working on android e-commerce project, I am using sqlite database to store data.
I need to update my database each and every time. My question is if i upload my app in android market, how can i update my database every day.I know about android versioning concept if i update version of the my apk , how people who are using my app will know that my app is updated.
Please give me a clear idea on this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution for this problem. It will be better if you host a web service that will serve the update information. You can do it for free. GoogleAppEngine provides this feature. Serve JSON file from web, parse it in you application.  Each time your app launches, write code to check for update information. OR check once in week or some other strategy. This might be tougher way of doing but you can provide more efficient and flexibility through this.

Answer (score 0):

> if i upload my app in android market, how can i update my database
>   every day

You can do this stuff using Web services call to your data server .

now you might have a question in your mind about users devices battery ,

if you **continually**  call those web services  **your device battery gonna loose  lot.**

or

if you call this web service in some **specific interval**  then app user might **miss the actuate time** when data has loaded already .

so i suggest to use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)  for could push notification .

```
How its works in your project :
```

- When you data will update on server , then there should be one script on server side which send message to GCM server with some required field of identification of that application package
- when you device receive that message using your [GCM receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)  you may need to update your database as you did so far .

Comment: thanks @dhams for your valuable reply , is it not possible with the sqlite database?

Comment: @Nareshkumarkondapalli all you need to do is parse those data from server and update it on your local database in direct way .